# A good way to merge files according to the file name python or bash

Tags: python, bash

I have thousands of zipped csv files named like this:

```
result-20120705-181535.csv.gz
```

181535 means 18:15:35, now I want to merge these files on daily basis(I have data over a week, all named like the above example), from 2:00 am in the morning till 2:00 am the next day,then moved the processed files into a folder called merged

so in the current folder, I have tons of .csv.gz files, and I want to scan the names, merge everything like `20120705-02*, 20120705-03*`...until `20120706-01*` into `20120705-result.csv.gz`, then move `20120705-02*, 20120705-03*`...until `20120706-01*` files into a folder called merged, and started to find the next day's data: `20120706-02*.....20120707-01*`

I am wondering whether to use python or bash script to do it, and how?

Comment: No reason to use bash there - even if you are confronted with a task that you don't know how to do in Python - let's suppose "ungzip" a file, it is a matter of doing `os.system("gunzip %s" % filename)` - so you have all tools you have in Bash, and the consistency and ease to read/maintain of Python

Comment: What do you mean by 'merge'? Just group in the same directory or really extract the CSV files and append them all (in sequence) into one big file?

Comment: @rody_o I mean to append them into one big file

Comment: Since you mentioned bash, I assume you are to do this in Linux right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a textfile containing these lines:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir merged
shopt -s extglob

d1=$1
d2=$(date -d "$d1 +1 day")

for f in result-@($d1-@(0[2-9]|[1-2][0-9])|$d2-0[01])*.csv.gz ; do
  gzip -cd $f
  mv $f merged/$f
done | gzip > $d1-result.csv.gz
```

and save it with a `.sh` extention (say, myscript.sh). Next, in a terminal, type

```
chmod +x myscript.sh
```

Now you can type things like

```
./myscript.sh 20120705
```

which will then do as you described.

To automatically execute this on a daily basis, you can put a line in your `/etc/crontab` file, something like

```
2 2 * * * root ./myscript.sh
```

assuming creating the last .csv.gz file takes 1 minute, plus 1 extra minute just to be sure :)

For this way of automation to work properly, the script above needs to be modified a bit. Assuming it will then operate on the **current day**, change the two lines defining the dates:

```
d1=$(date +%Y%m%d -d "now -1 day")
d2=$(date +%Y%m%d)
```

That should do. As always, *test it thoroughly* before automating it!

Comment: minor change in the glob pattern : moved the star out of parentheses

Answer (score 0):

This answer is completely untested, but hopefully it will give a place to work from:

```
import datetime
import glob
from collections import defaultdict
import gzip
import os
import shutil

def day(fname):
    """
    Finds the "logical" day (e.g. the day minus 2 hours since your days 
    run from 2AM
    """
    d=datetime.datetime.strptime('result-%Y%m%d-%H%M%S.csv.gz')-datetime.timedelta(hours=2)
    return d.strftime('%Y%m%d')

files=sorted(glob.glob('result-*.csv.gz'))
cat_together=defaultdict(list)
for f in files:
    cat_together[day].append(f)

os.mkdir('merged')
for d,files in cat_together.items():
    outfile=gzip.open(d+'-result.csv.gz','wb')
    for f in files:
        gfile=gzip.open(f)
        outfile.write(gfile.read())
        gfile.close()
        shutil.move(f,'merged')
    outfile.close()
```