# how to open some specific files using python

Tags: python, datetime, glob

I have a couple of files named as `yyyymmdd-hhmmss.csv.gz`. Now I want to open each day's first file from 02am, do some process, one by one.

My files are:

```
...
20120706-015923.txt
20120706-015934.txt 
20120706-020008.txt
20120706-020030.txt
...
20120707-015934.txt
20120707-020005.txt
20120707-020015.txt
...
```

So I want to go through the file name in this folder first, to find `20120706-020008.txt` which is the first file from the 02am that day, then I had a script to read all the lines and do some process. My problem is, how to tell this script to find these files?
`20120706-020008.txt`, `20120707-020015.txt`, `20120708-02`....

Comment: How does `yyyymmdd-hhmmss.csv.gz` relate to the `.txt` files you list?

Comment: Will the file you open always have "-02" in it, or could the first file after 2:00 also be after, say, 3:00 or 4:00?

Comment: Did you read my answer from your previous question?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/11399167/748858

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some simple use of `for loop` and `dictionary`:

```
import glob
import datetime

dic={}

for f in glob.glob('*-*.txt'):
    d = datetime.datetime.strptime(f, '%Y%m%d-%H%M%S.txt')
    if d.hour < 2:
        continue
    if not d.day in dic or dic[d.day][0] > d.time:
        dic[d.day] = (d.time, f)

for t, f in dic.values():
    print f
```

---

**Given the following files:**

```
20120706-015923.txt
20120706-015934.txt 
20120706-020008.txt
20120706-020030.txt
20120707-015934.txt
20120707-020005.txt
20120707-020015.txt
```

**output will be:**

```
20120706-020008.txt
20120707-020005.txt
```

Comment: `dic.keys()` is redundant as by default `in` will return the keys in a dictionary.

Comment: @BigYellowCactus I don't understand what you are talking about. checking `x in dic` will check if `x` is in the keys as BurhanKhalid said. using `.keys` will just create a list in py2 and make the membership check O(N) when you could just do `d.day in dic`

Comment: Sorry, my bad :-) I mixed some things up.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`glob`](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) module to iterate over the files:

```
import glob
for f in glob.glob('20120707-*'):
    # do something with f
```

The above code means: iterate over all files whose filename starts with `20120707-`. The `*` symbol matches the rest of the filename.

You can compute the prefix of the file in your Python code using the [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) module (see the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) to see what values you can use for `strftime`):

```
import datetime
today = datetime.date.today()
print today.strftime("%Y%m%d")
```

Combined the code becomes:

```
import datetime    
import glob

today = datetime.date.today()
pattern = "{0}-*".format(today.strftime("%Y%m%d"))
for f in glob.glob(pattern):
    # do something with f
```

You can also enforce that `glob` should only look for `.txt` files by including that in the search pattern:

```
pattern = "{0}-*.txt".format(today.strftime("%Y%m%d"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to *group* the files chronologically to times between 02am and 02am, sort them and take the first one:

```
import itertools as it
import glob
import datetime

def map_to_day_2am(fn):
    # parses filename, substracts two hours and returns the date
    return (datetime.strptime(fn, '%Y%m%d-%H%M%S.txt') -
            datetime.timedelta(hours=2)).date()

for day, daily_fns_iter in it.groupby(sorted(glob.glob('*.txt')),
                                      key=map_to_day_2am):
    print min(daily_fns_iter)
```

Comment: Downvoter -- What is wrong with this?  This seems like what he wants to me (+1).

Comment: Might not be most "beginner friendly", maybe that's why it was downvoted (I didn't downvote it).

Comment: Maybe because it is wrong? It will list files which are from *before* 2am.

Comment: @BigYellowCactus - yes, it will list these files with the *previous* day. If it happens, that the first file after Monday 2am ist Tuesday 1am, then it should be listed too.

Comment: @eumiro OK, I think that's a matter of definition. But it is still wrong. Given the input files in the question, your code will output `20120706-015923.txt`, `20120706-020008.txt` and `20120707-020005.txt`. Why is `20120706-015923.txt` in this list? There are only two days (2012/07/06 and 2012/07/07), but three files?

Comment: @BigYellowCactus - possibly I remembered the OP's other question linked by mgilson in the comments saying that his "day" goes "from 2:00 am in the morning till 2:00 am the next day"

Comment: @eumiro That would make sense, then.